Manga about a female lead who is accidently killed by a god, then taught how to make potions and transported to another world
I remember reading a manga (not a manhwa or manhua) where a girl from Japan was killed by accident because of a god from another world who was trying to close a rift between their worlds, and then one of the Japanese gods confronts the other god. In return, the girl is then taught how to make potions from gods. After being taught how to make potion from the gods, the god then sends the girl to his world.
Upon arriving, she tried to sell the potions she made, but got ignored or so, because her hair is black. Then a guy with black hair, who looks like a knight, shows up and brings the girl to a place where people with black hair receive better treatment. When they reach the knight's house, it turns out that the knight is a noble and has a fiancée, but his cousin is sleeping with his fiancée and then I forgot what happens.
The manga is not:

I Shall Survive Using Potions!


Is this The Transfer Destination Was a World with few Pharmacists...?

Yui lost her job when the place she worked went under. Then she was whisked to another world because of a god's mistake and now can't return to Japan! Resigning herself to living in this new world, she becomes a pharmacist after the god recommended it. Yui learns practically all pharmacy skills, and away she goes! As she begins her journey toward finding a permanent home, are her god-chosen skills actually better than she can ever imagine?!

A Japanese woman named Yui Suzuhara is walking down a street when she suddenly finds herself in a field in another world, where she's greeted by a god, Antos, and a goddess, Tsukuyomi. Antos explains that he's in charge of the world Yui has arrived in, Zebalsh, while Tsukuyomi is in charge of Japan, and that he accidently caused her to fall into Zebalsh while trying to close a dimensional hole between it and Earth.



He says she can't go back to Earth, but gives her skills and items and teaches her how to make potions to help her live comfortably in Zebalsh, along with providing some information about the country she'll be in, like the fact there are humans, elves, dwarves, dragons and demons there. Tsukuyomi also gives Yui an adventurers' guild tag, the new name of 'Rin,' and an amulet from the Japanese gods, then sends her on her way.
Soon after, Yui arrives on foot at a nearby city and tries to sell some potions at the adventurers' guild there, but the man she speaks to gives her a funny look and offers a price for the potions that she knows is less than reasonable, thanks to her 'analyze' skill. She declines to sell her potions for that price and leaves, but catches the eye of a knight named Earhart Gautino on her way out.
Earhart later catches up to her and explains that people with black hair are subject to discrimination in this world, since dark hair is a sign of magic power, and the more magic one has, the darker their hair is.



He also travels with her to the capital city, where she plans to open her own store, and offers to let her stay at his home. When they arrive at his home, a large mansion, she meets his family, including his younger brother, Carl, and his fiancée, Leila, whom he knows are having an affair.
You can read the full manga at Alpha Manga.
